# Track android users under a network tower

Tags: android, gps, gsm

I want to track android users around me from my android app. But the problem is if they HAVE NOT INSTALLED my app on their phone then what would be the procedure?
Or is there a LEGAL way to do so either from an android application or from a website?

Comment: so, to sum this up, you want to track cellphone users without their consent?

Comment: It is never legal to track someone's position without his/her agreement.

Comment: you can't do such thing like spying on someone without installing any software on their device. it's not only illegal, it's also impossible (from an android app)

Comment: "But the problem is if they HAVE NOT INSTALLED my app on their phone then what would be the procedure?" -- walk up to them and politely ask them to install your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible and illegal.

Comment: Be careful about making statements about legality. It might be illegal  where you live but legal elsewhere (or vice-versa). I agree it is probably not legal in the vast majority of countries though.

Comment: Ok, my mistake :), sorry